# How does certificate manager work for multiple domians

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, cname

I'm working with certification manager, Can someone pls explain me certification manager for multiple certificates.

For example

```
domain_name = foo.dev
alternate_domian_names = *.foo.dev , bar.com
```

so should create CNAME record for all 3 domain name `(foo.dev,*foo.dev and bar.com)` and validate for all the 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the DNS `foo.dev,*.foo.dev` these seem to same parent DNS so single validation will work and you will need to add `bar.com` so All you will need to create 2 CNAME for the above DNS validation one for `foo.dev` and one for `bar.com`.

You can also compare CNAME record for `foo.com` or `*.foo.com` it should be same that is generated by AWS ACM.

You can attach a [maximum 10](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-limits.html) Domain names for each ACM certificate by default.

**Understanding Automatic Domain Validation**

> To validate a domain, ACM sends automated, periodic HTTPS requests to
> it. For domains that start with `www.`, ACM also sends HTTPS requests to
> the parent domain. For example, if your domain is `www.example.com`, ACM
> sends periodic requests to `www.example.com` and to `example.com`. For
> domains that don't start with `www.`, ACM also sends HTTPS requests to
> `www.domain`. **ACM treats wildcard domain names (for example, `*.example.com`) the same as the parent domain.** For examples, see the following table.

[How ACM domain validation works](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/how-domain-validation-works.html)

Comment: so in my case its not validating for bar.com, what could be the issue?

Comment: Did you add a valid entry for bar.com?

Comment: Ah yeah there was no entry, Got it , So what if , after the certificate is issued , someone deletes the record set for that domain, can the certificate still be used?

Comment: Yes you can still use the certificate, certificate has no thing to do with records once it issued, but that records will help for next renewal

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I can't find documentation describing this, but at least when using DNS validation, you have to create a DNS record for each Subject Alternative Name.